# Can't log in to YouTrack

Tags: authentication, youtrack, jetbrains-toolbox

I can't log in to YouTrack. My teammate sent me a link to join to his project but when I want to log in it says: Incorrect username or password. I'm sure that the username and the password is correct because it's the same as my JetBrains profile.
How can I solve this problem and join to this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually JetBrains account and YouTrack account are not the same, so you shouldn't be able to log in to YouTrack with your JetBrains credentials. It can be possible only if your YouTrack is explicitly integrated with JetBrains Account to allow authentication with JBA credentials.
So when you are invited to join a project, you are expected to create a new account or to log in via configured auth modules (like JBA, Google, GitHub). The solution here depends on the YouTrack setup, so if my answer doesn't help, please provide more details about what you see on the login screen and how exactly you were invited to join the project. Your teammate should either create an account for you, or send you an invitation link, or this particular YouTrack instance should allow new users to create accounts. You can read more about each option here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Create-User-Accounts.html#InvitingNewUsers